# Check for zero lines output from command over SSH

Tags: linux, bash, error-handling, ssh

If I do the following, and the network is down, then the zero case will be executed, which it shouldn't.

```
case "$(ssh -n $host zfs list -t snapshot -o name -H | grep "tank/fs" | wc -l | awk '{print $1}')" in
    0)  # do something
        ;;
    1)  # do something else
        ;;
    *)  # fail
esac
```

Earlier in the script I check that I can SSH to `$host`, but today I found this problem, where the network failed right after my check.

If I check the return value from the SSH command, then I will always get the return value from `awk` as it is executed last.

**Question**

How do I insure that I actually count zero lines that `zfs` outputted, and not zero lines from a failed SSH connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say:

```
set -o pipefail
```

at the beginning of your script (or before the `case` statement).

Moreover, check for the return code of the command before executing the `case` statement:

```
set -o pipefail
$value=$(ssh -n $host zfs list -t snapshot -o name -H | grep "tank/fs" | wc -l | awk '{print $1}')
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
   case $value in
     ...
   esac
fi
```

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> `pipefail`
>
> If set, the return value of a pipeline is the value of the last
>   (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all
>   commands in the pipeline exit successfully. This option is disabled by
>   default.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it still goes through `case 0`. **EDIT**: with you added code, `$? == 0` the logic should work.

Comment: I think this is an ugly solution though. The `grep`/`wc`/`awk` commands will get executed `locally` instead of on remote *when* ssh fails, that's why it's not working as intended. My solution should be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

How about this (commands after ssh **shouldn't** get executed locally):

```
"$(ssh -n $host 'zfs list -t snapshot -o name -H | grep "tank/fs" | wc -l | awk \'{print $1}\')'"
```

Note how I single quoted the command for ssh to run on the remote machine. Also escaped the `'` for `awk` like `\'`. Check the return value of the call and only act when it returns success.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem, because the whole pipeline can fail, and the empty case happens when exit status isn't checked rather than short-circuiting earlier.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried the original line locally. ssh failing means pipeline commands get executed locally and `case 0` fires due to `wc -l` echoing a `0`. In my solution everything in between `''` becomes an argument to ssh and `case 0` doesn't fire when `ssh` fails. However that just happens to be the case when doing string comparison. If `ssh` would have printed a `0` line it would have matched `case 0` too ofc. Only doing action on a return value of `0` sounds like a good idea and I originally planned on adding it, but canceled the edit for some reason :)