# How to get error code of an app in pipeline?

Tags: bash, error-handling, pipeline

```
#!/bin/sh
$(./tool < input.data > output.another_data 2> errors)
echo $?
```

Hello there. I had had such stupidly simple script for debugging my tool. Yet redirecting stderr only to the file without printing it to the screen isn't that handy. Found that `tee` comes useful in such cases.
So came to such version.
`$(./tool < input.data > output.another_data 2>&1 | tee errors.txt)`
And here I'm stuck. Instead of getting tool's error code I'm getting tee's.
Could you please give advice how to get tool's not tee's err in the pipeline?
Thanks in advance :-)

So, here I am. Now it reads line 4: =: command not found about the `$value=...` line.
What could be wrong here?
**===================

EDIT:**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o pipefail

$value=$(./tool < input.data > output.another_data 2> errors)
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
        case $value in
                1) echo "out of bounds"
                ;;
                2) echo "heap err"
                ;;
        esac
fi
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for the `pipefail` option.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19027203/2235132) answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check for zero lines output from command over SSH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027075/check-for-zero-lines-output-from-command-over-ssh)

Comment: @devnull got such script with the error. Could you please explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21183205/2235132) answer explains how you could get the return code of all the commands in the pipeline.

Comment: Moreover, as per your edit you shouldn't be saying `$value=...`, rather say `value=...`

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21183205/2235132) answer explains how you could get the return code of all the commands in the pipeline. –  devnull

Moreover, as per your edit you shouldn't be saying `$value=...`, rather say `value=...` –  devnull